# Format ZonedDateTime and Instant to different string format

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, date-formatting

I read over the literature for ZonedDate and Instant and found that I can convert a local time to utc via the below:

```
LocalDate d = LocalDate.now();
LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(00, 00, 00);
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(d, time, zone);
System.out.println(zonedDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));

Instant instant = zonedDateTime.toInstant();
System.out.println(instant);
```

The problem is the output looks like this:

```
2018-11-26T00:00:00
2018-11-26T08:00:00Z
```

I'm trying to get both strings in the format of "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" but am having a hard time getting anything to work properly. Since I am using the output to query an MYSQL database I could just manually do:

```
String zoneDate = zonedDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
String utcDate = zonedDateTime.toInstant().toString();
zoneDate = zoneDate.replace('T', ' ').replace('Z', ' ');
utcDate = utcDate.replace('T', ' ').replace('Z', ' ');
```

With my new output being:

```
2018-11-26 00:00:00
2018-11-26 08:00:00
```

But I feel like this is bad practice and there should be a method to convert to the proper format within the classes. Is there such a way to perform formatting as above from the default classes?

Comment: `System.out.println(instant);` will call `Instant.toString()` so you are bound to use what that returns. Instead you should use a formatter to produce a formatted string much like you do with `zonedDateTime.format(...)`, e.g. via `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.format(instant)`.

Comment: I understand that however the problem is that I have been unable to find a proper formatter for a MYSQL datetime object, in the form above. I'm calling the toString() method because it's required to get the string itself if setting it in a declaration. The method you describe of doing DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.format(instant) throws an exception and the stacktrace states "java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: Year"

Comment: Well you might need to use another formatter or define your own format. Besides that passing a string to MySQL is probably not the best way to do it, I'd try to convert that `Instant` to `java.sql.Date` or something similar (depending an what the driver supports, I've not been using plain JDBC in a while).

Comment: If your JDBC driver doesn’t accept an unformatted `Instant`, give it an `OffsetDateTime` and stop worrying about format at all. This is the correct way to do it, and also the easy and troublefree one. Also don’t use two digits `00`. While it’s visually pleasing and will work, using `08` or `09` won’t compile, so it’s a bad habit to get into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow snippet below.

```
LocalDate d = LocalDate.now();
LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(d, time, zone);
String zoneDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(zonedDateTime);
ZonedDateTime utcZonedDateTime = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of(ZoneOffset.UTC.getId()));
String utcZoneDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(utcZonedDateTime);

System.out.println(zoneDate);
System.out.println(utcZoneDate);
```

Output for this is

```
2018-11-26 02:20:08
2018-11-26 10:20:08
```

For more information please visit java doc -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: How do you resolve the issue with Instant? I've been using it to convert to UTC.

Comment: If your purpose is to take UTC time from the offset value, you do not need to use instant. instead convert ZonedDateTime to use UTC ZoneId.

Comment: ZonedDateTime utcZonedDateTime = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of(ZoneOffset.UTC.getId()));

Comment: I edited the above to include that, it works just like I wanted. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Lowercase `hh` is incorrect for hour of day and will give you incorrect results (quite often). You need uppercase `HH`.